# Issue with Animated Counter Functionality on Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I'm encountering an issue with an animated counter on my website. The counter is intended to simulate a statistic and works perfectly on desktop browsers. However, when accessed on mobile devices in a production environment, there seems to be a problem with parsing or conversion that resets any number above 999, consequently resetting the initial number.

Here's the relevant HTML code snippet:

```
<span id="counter">4898988</span><br />
```

Here's the relevant JavaScript code snippet:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const counterElement = document.getElementById('counter');
  console.log('counterElement:', counterElement); // log the counterElement
  counterElement.textContent = `${parseInt(counterElement.textContent, 10).toLocaleString()} USD`; // format the initial number
  console.log('counterElement.textContent after formatting:', counterElement.textContent); // log the textContent after formatting
  animateCount(counterElement);
  
  // Animate the counter
  function animateCount(targetElement) {
    console.log('targetElement in animateCount:', targetElement); // log the targetElement in animateCount
    let count = parseInt(targetElement.textContent.replace(/,/g, ''), 10);
    console.log('count after parsing:', count); // log the count after parsing
    const finalCount = count + Math.floor(Math.random() * 31); // generate a random number between 0 and 30
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (count < finalCount) {
        count++;
        targetElement.textContent = `${count.toLocaleString()} USD`;
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
        setTimeout(() => animateCount(targetElement), Math.random() * 9000 + 5000); // wait for a random period between 5 and 14 seconds before starting the next cycle
      }
    }, 100);
  }
});
```

Console log:

```
[Log] counterElement:
<span id="counter">4 898 988 USD</span>
[Log] after formatting: – "4 898 988 USD"
[Log] animateCount: 
<span id="counter">4 898 988 USD</span>
[Log] count after parsing: – 4
```

As you can see, the 'let count =' line seems to not parse correctly a number above 999.

Comment: `parseInt("4 898 988 USD", 10)` gives 4, because parsing stops at the first space. Even on my desktop browser.

Comment: You're right, same for me on mine. But my code snipper works perfectly, how ? And how should I fix it then ?

Comment: `.replace(/[^-0-9.]/g, '')` would remove everything but digits, the decimal point and a minus sign.

Comment: Already tried, not working.

Comment: Apparently, your mobile device uses a different locale that inserts spaces (or something looking like spaces) instead of commas between groups of three digits.

Comment: Possible, actually I noticed that those spaces don't look as normal spaces, but again. They are narrower. Any hint ? These spaces should come from the JavaScript formatting above, loaded on iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of `toLocaleString` changes based on the user's local, which makes parsing it much more complicated than it should be.
A solution is to keep track of the count in a variable, rather than parsing it from the DOM every time:
Working example: https://codepen.io/jacob_124/pen/JjVbjoL

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  const counterElement = document.getElementById("counter");
  // Initialize number based off of text
  const num = parseInt(counterElement.textContent, 10);

  counterElement.textContent = `${num.toLocaleString()} USD`; // format the initial number
  console.log(
    "counterElement.textContent after formatting:",
    counterElement.textContent
  ); // log the textContent after formatting
  animateCount(counterElement, num);

  // Animate the counter
  function animateCount(targetElement, count) {
    const finalCount = count + Math.floor(Math.random() * 31); // generate a random number between 0 and 30
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (count < finalCount) {
        count++;
        targetElement.textContent = `${count.toLocaleString()} USD`;
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
        setTimeout(
          () => animateCount(targetElement, count),
          Math.random() * 9000 + 5000
        ); // wait for a random period between 5 and 14 seconds before starting the next cycle
      }
    }, 100);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and code. However, it is still not working. the counter resets over 999. Actually your code works well on desktop and simulated mobile. But not in prod on an iPhone.

Comment: @MarcKch what browser are you testing with?

Comment: IOS Safari iphone 15, paybcn.com is the website if you want to check

Comment: @MarcKch are you sure you implemented the code above? It gets rid of the inconsistencies with parseInt/toLocaleString, I don't see any reason it wouldn't work. The initial number must not have any commas or spaces in it. Could you add some console logs and share what the values are when it fails on mobile?

Answer (score 1):

The original code directly manipulated the textContent for number formatting, violating the DRY principle. I introduced a separate function, formatNumber, to handle number formatting, enhancing readability and maintainability while adhering to best practices.

Comment: Welcome, please refrain from posting only code. Your answer should explain what was the mistake, why and how you corrected it.

Comment: The original code lacked modularization by directly formatting numbers in the event listener. I introduced a separate function for number formatting, improving code readability and adhering to the DRY principle.